# How can I get rid of the error that I keep getting?

Tags: java

I can't figure out whats wrong or why it won't run. Ive been here for hours messing around with it and I would really like some help. Its for a school project in my intro to programing class. Thanks a lot

so basically heres whats supposed to happen. you type your bill paid the the amount of tip. after that a message will pop up and tell you the percentage of your tip and give a little message about your tip. I keep getting different error messages every time I try to fix the error, another one comes up

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,
            "Enter the Total Bill");
    double bill = Double.parseDouble(input1);
    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "How much tip did you leave?");
    double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(input2);
    double tipPercent = (tipAmount / bill);
    if (tipPercent < 0 || tipPercent > 1) {
        System.out.println("I don't think that's that correct. ");
    } else if (tipPercent >= 0 || tipPercent <= 0.05 ) {
        System.out.println("You left a " + tipPercent * 100 "% tip. "
        + "\nBad sercice or enpty wallet? ");
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.05 && tipPercent <= 0.1 ) {
        System.out.println("You left a " + tipPercent * 100 "% tip. "
        + "\nI think you could have done better");
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.1 && tipPercent <= 0.2 ) {
        System.out.println("You left a " + tipPercent * 100 "% tip. "
        + "\nNot too bad.";
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.2 && tipPercent <= 0.3 ) {
        System.out.println("You left a " + tipPercent * 100 "% tip. "
        + "\nSomeone's a bit generous.";
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.3 ) {
        System.out.println("You left a " + tipPercent * 100 "% tip. "
        + "\nBIG MONEY!!.";
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

    }        
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for your question. It would be very helpful if you could tell us the exact error message that you are receiving.

Comment: `"You left a " + tipPercent * 100 "% tip. "` this is not valid syntax.... Maybe you mean something like: `"You left a " + (tipPercent * 100) + "% tip. "`

Comment: It would be useful if you add the complete error message. Humans are no compilers, it's hard to spot the problem without the message.

Answer (score 0):

You had two main issues:

1. message variable is not defined
2. Last 3 `System.out.println` statements were missing closing `);`

With small refactoring it works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,
            "Enter the Total Bill");
    double bill = Double.parseDouble(input1);
    String input2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "How much tip did you leave?");
    double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(input2);
    double tipPercent = (tipAmount / bill);
    String message = getMessage(tipPercent); // you were missing message variable
    System.out.println(message);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

}

private static String getMessage(double tipPercent) {
    if (tipPercent < 0 || tipPercent > 1) {
        return "I don't think that's that correct. ";
    } else if (tipPercent >= 0 || tipPercent <= 0.05 ) {
        return "You left a " + tipPercent * 100 +"% tip. "
                + "\nBad sercice or enpty wallet? ";
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.05 && tipPercent <= 0.1 ) {
        return "You left a " + tipPercent * 100 +"% tip. "
                + "\nI think you could have done better";
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.1 && tipPercent <= 0.2 ) {
        return "You left a " + tipPercent * 100 +"% tip. "
                + "\nNot too bad.";
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.2 && tipPercent <= 0.3 ) {
        return "You left a " + tipPercent * 100 +"% tip. "
                + "\nSomeone's a bit generous.";
    } else if (tipPercent > 0.3 ) {
        return "You left a " + tipPercent * 100 +"% tip. "
                + "\nBIG MONEY!!.";

    }
    return "Ooops!!"; // edge case, when no if-else statement matches
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. I couldn't figure it out but you all helped so much

Comment: Dominic If this answer suites  you, and you don't have anymore questions, please accept the answer or close the question.